# How to configure SSL Certificates in Postman App for Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: postman

How to configure SSL Certificates in Postman App for Windows. I have installed Postman App for Windows 7 64bit. I have certificate format of P12 and PEM.  If i supply that in Postman Settings --> Certificates tab in CRT file. But, did not get the certificate by postman. what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

Certificates tab is not available in Chrome extension. You need to download Postman desktop app.